# Where does China send election observers (and they are accepted)?

Tags: china, election-observers

I found one [source](https://www.newagebd.net/article/220784/india-russia-china-among-9-countries-confirm-sending-election-observers) saying that China sent election observers to Bangladesh, last year. Are there other countries where they do this (and their observers are accepted, of course)?

Comment: [Cambodia](https://www.voanews.com/a/china-welcomes-cambodia-s-election-results-amid-western-rebukes-/7201714.html), [Madagascar](https://allafrica.com/stories/201312201229.html), [Zimbabwe](https://www.scmp.com/news/china/diplomacy/article/3232660/friendly-china-ready-work-zimbabwe-after-mnangagwa-election)... Keep Googling and I'm sure you'll find more.

Comment: @BrianZ: did they ever send them to Pakistan though? I seems they generally went to China's allies/sphere https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/74626/which-countries-if-any-does-china-characterize-as-its-allies

Comment: If that's your real question that's not what you asked above.